# Windows 7 graphic driver

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I recently installed Windows 7 on my computer for a multi-boot system with XP.

Now my problem is, every time I install the correct graphic driver for my Windows 7 OS. The installer would say that the one that I'm going to install is of lower version than the one that is currently installed (a graphic driver that maybe installed along with Windows 7).
So, I installed it. But when I restarted the computer the interface became a mess. It's like a venetian blinds so I needed to reinstall the driver again and again every time I turn on the computer. Is there a possible solution to this problem?

Because the graphic driver that comes along with Windows 7 cannot adjust the contrast and brightness.
It's so bright for me.

Comment: What graphics adapter do you have?

Comment: VGA driver ver:15.12.75.3.1912
for g31m-s asrock motherboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3100. I would visit the Intel website and use their driver detection utility to get the latest version. Intel has very good Windows 7 support so I would be surprised to see the latest driver from the installer stuff up.

Comment: yeah I  even tried in intel and used the driver detection utility, but its still the same thing.

Comment: Well, the latest driver is 15.12.75.4.1930. You may want to try that. Otherwise, what is wrong with changing the contrast and brightness on your monitor?